# How to apply hover effects to a selected scatter point in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple Highcharts scatter plot that allows point selection.  The normal unselected points have the default Highcharts hover effect, and I would like the selected points to also have a hover effect.  The `plotOptions.scatter.marker.states` options seem to allow setting the colors for each of the states, but `select` and `hover` seem mutually exclusive.  I don't see a way to set the attributes for a point that is both selected and hovered.  How can I do this?

[image]

Here's a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/b7kaf9dc/2/

```
    "plotOptions": {"scatter": {
      "allowPointSelect": true,
      "marker": {
        "states": {
            "select": {
                "fillColor": "magenta",
            },
          "normal": {
                "fillColor": "green",
            },
          "hover": {
            "fillColor": "orange",
            "radiusPlus": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }},
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `marker.states.select` as a hover.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      marker: {
        states: {
          select: {
            lineColor: 'rgba(100,100,200, 0.25)',
            fillColor: null,
            lineWidth: 10,
            radius: 6,
          },
          hover: {
            lineColor: 'rgba(100,100,200, 0.25)',
            fillColor: null,
            lineWidth: 10,
            radius: 6,
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Then modify the core Highcharts code and extend it to the appropriate behavior.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Point.prototype.firePointEvent = function(eventType, eventArgs, defaultFunction) {
    var point = this,
      series = this.series,
      seriesOptions = series.options;
    // load event handlers on demand to save time on mouseover/out
    if (seriesOptions.point.events[eventType] ||
      (point.options &&
        point.options.events &&
        point.options.events[eventType])) {
      point.importEvents();
    }
    // add default handler if in selection mode
    if (eventType === 'click' && seriesOptions.allowPointSelect) {
      defaultFunction = function(event) {
        // Control key is for Windows, meta (= Cmd key) for Mac, Shift
        // for Opera.
        if (point.select) { // #2911
          point.select(null, true);
                    
        }
      };
    }
    H.fireEvent(point, eventType, eventArgs, defaultFunction);
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Concept of a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/79cmw28g/2/